# Using symbols to map after plucking from joined tables with same column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently, I have joined multiple tables using the `join` method, and I need to pluck out several columns, which I need to map into something else. Here's what I mean:

```
A.join( ... long sql statements involving model B and C...)
    .pluck("A.id", "A.name", "B.id", "B.name" ...) # you get the idea
    .map( |result|
       # Then to use the various attributes, I was using result[0] to access A.id and so on
```

I was wondering is it possible to convert my attributes in my pluck to symbols like `:A_id` or `:B_name`? The reason I have to use "table_name.attribute" is due to the tables having columsn with the same name. If possible I was looking for:

```
A.join( ... long sql statements involving model B and C...)
    .pluck(A_id, A_name, B.id, B_name ...) 
    .map( |A_id, A_name, B.id, B_name ...| ...)
```

Symbols would make it easier so that when I map, I do not need to use indexing in order to access my attributes? For example, I can straight up use `:A_id` instead of `result[0]` in the above example.

Would really help with readability since I'm plucking quite a lot of attributes and my join is pretty big (so there's plenty of columns with the same name), and it definitely looks messy with `result[0]` to `result[10]` all over in my `map` function.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

`.pluck` returns an array and it's a bit difficult to work with for your scenario, but a combination of `select` and `AS` (alias_name) does the trick.

```
A.join( ... long sql statements involving model B and C...)
   .select("A.id AS AID", "A.name AS ANAME", "B.id AS BID", "B.name AS BNAME" ...)
   .each { |result| p result.AID ...}
```

The difference between `pluck` and `select`, is that `select` returns an array of `A` objects having those aliases defined in `select` as attributes.

Comment: May I ask does using `select` in this case cause my code to run slower? Ps as I don't really do this often so pardon if I do not exactly know the difference, but I've read that using `select` could be significantly slower as compared to using `pluck`? Which is why I was using `pluck` here.

Comment: `pluck` is the same thing as `select` (you can look at the query is generates) the only difference is what it returns. `pluck` returns an array of values which should take less memory than `select`, which returns `A` records, records that are instantiated, etc.

Comment: You can do the same query with `pluck` and `select` and throw a `.to_sql` at the end to see the query it makes.

Comment: Oh, for pluck to_sql does not work because it returns an array..

Comment: `select` should not be slower than `pluck`. it all comes down to how much data you are querying. Just test see how it works.